# Namespaces. Setting up Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't get access to classes that should be in `System.Windows`.
Intellisense shows only two points.

[image]

**Problem solved by adding reference to WindowsBase.dll**

Comment: What class are you trying to access? Where are you writing that line (inside a class definition, inside a method, etc)? Please provide more information.

Comment: Did you add reference to System.Windows.dll?

Comment: Are you sure you have selected the correct new project. I.E A new windows form project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click the project node and click **Add Reference**.
2. In the **Add Reference** dialog box, select the tab **Assemblies** - **Framework**
3. Select the  **System.Windows.dll**, and then click **OK**.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx#To%20add%20a%20reference%20in%20Visual%20C#)